# How to change the theme of my windows phone app?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Currently I am working on windows phone app development. I have completed 50% of my project. Now Can I change my **theme from black to white**??
If so how can I do it??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the Theme of your Application only.
You will not set the windows phone's theme programattically.

For setting the Theme for your Application, please refer this link,

> [Change the Current Application Theme in windows phone](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2012/01/phonethememanager/)

I hope You will get the Answer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply !But This seems to be like a third party! ?Is it not posssible without this one?? FYI : i just want to change between the inbuilt two themes(dark and light) only.

Comment: I think as far as i know, this is best and everywhere you will get this solution.
And yes for your Solution, You have to pass the ThemeResource for whole Application. For more Information please refer this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769545(v=vs.105).aspx